# Docker container on NAS. need shared folder for SQL-database

Tags: sql-server, docker

on a QNAP I installed a Docker container for running SQL-Server 2019 on linux. I can start the SQL-Server and connect by Management studio.

But now I want to import an existing database from host, which cannot be done because when trying to restore the database I cannot change to a host backup folder. The opening file dialog stays at /var/opt/mssql/data  which is the folder for SQL-data within the container.

Now I need to mount a shared folder for container and host.

There a few tutorials and videos but docker world with bin/bash, etc. is not at all familiar for me, so I cant get through this.

Does anyone can give me dummy explanation what to do and HOW to do??

In docker I can just open "terminal", but then I am lost.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you expose the backup file(s) via a SMB/CIFS share? [BACKUP TO DISK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-devices-sql-server#specify-a-universal-naming-convention-unc-name) and [RESTORE FROM DISK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql) support UNC paths.

Comment: No, this is my problem. The .bak is still in a visible folder on the NAS, and opening the restore wizzard in SSMS I cannot "leave" the file structure /var/opt/mssql/data which is inside the container. Therefore i want to create a shared folder to store the .bak and then access this folder via SSMS and import the database from there.
But I found another way to get it (almost) done: I used the export wizzard, who created the tables with data, but did not create primary keys. I need to set them manually.

Comment: Finally, I solved the transfer from an existing database to the docker on NAS through SSMS.
Maybe it was a kind of wrong thinking or I tried it the way I usually transfer database to another machine (by .bak-file), but I could connect to the SQL-Server running on the NAS and the server running on my machine. So I just exported data from one to the other.